# Package: otrs-4.0.7-01.noarch Requires: perl(Template) while installing OTRS in centos 6

Tags: installation, centos, perl

While I was trying to install OTRS 4.0.7 in centos 6, an error occurred. I tried to Google it, but I cant get the results to resolve the issue.

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager <br>
Updating Red Hat repositories.<br>
Setting up Local Package Process<br>
Examining otrs-4.0.7-01.noarch.rpm: otrs-4.0.7-01.noarch<br>
Marking otrs-4.0.7-01.noarch.rpm to be installed<br>
Resolving Dependencies<br>
--> Running transaction check<br>
--> Package otrs.noarch 0:4.0.7-01 will be installed<br>
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Template) for package: otrs-4.0.7-01.noarch <br>
--> Finished Dependency Resolution<br>
Error: Package: otrs-4.0.7-01.noarch (/otrs-4.0.7-01.noarch)       Requires: perl(Template)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine is working fine here using:

## yum install otrs-4.0.7-01.noarch.rpm

The missing package is named perl-Template-Toolkit

This is on CentOS 6.6 (and I just did an yum update before the installation).

Hope that helps.

Regards,
CDJM